# Header Files Not Found (Wrong Path?)

Tags: c++, header-files, include-path

I am trying to compile the a program in Linux and the program contains the following header files:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Minuit2/FCNBase.h"
#include "FunctionMinimum.h"
#include "MnMigrad.h"
```

etc. The source file is in

```
home/christian/code
```

and the header files are all in

```
/home/christian/root/include/Minuit2
```

I am trying to compile by running the following command:

```
g++ -I /Minuit2 niminimzationExample.cpp -o niminimzationExample -L/Minuit2/lib -lMinuit2
```

But I get the following error message:

```
In file included from niminimzationExample.cpp:9:0:
/home/christian/root/include/Minuit2/FCNBase.h:13:10: fatal error: Minuit2/MnConfig.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Minuit2/MnConfig.h"
```

Because the compiler cannot find MnConfig.h which is the first header file inside of FCNBase.h. I have also tried to run

```
g++ -I /home/christian/root/include/Minuit2 niminimzationExample.cpp -o niminimzationExample -L/Minuit2/lib -lMinuit2
```

But I still get the same error. What is the write way to include the header files?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the parent directory of `#include "Minuit2/FCNBase.h"` to the include path as the include already has `Minuit2` in it's path.

Comment: `/Minuit2` is the path to `Minuit2` in the *root* directory (not the directory named `root` but the filsystem root). I recommend you use the full path to the directories. And use `<>` for your includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your header is at

```
/home/christian/root/include/Minuit2/FCNBase.h
```

Your `#include` or compile option is wrong.

Currently you are telling the compiler to search for

```
/Minuit2/Minuit2/FCNBase.h
```

or

```
/home/christian/root/include/Minuit2/Minuit2/FCNBase.h
```

You should specify an option

```
-I /home/christian/root/include
```

To have the compiler search for `Minuit2/FCNBase.h` in the directory `/home/christian/root/include`.

If you don't want to change the option, you should change the `#include` to

```
#include "FCNBase.h"
```

To have the compiler search for `FCNBase.h` in the directory `/home/christian/root/include/Minuit2`.